# iTMSTransporter upload behavior

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Does the iTMSTransporter upload method (see below) just upload to iTunes Connect? Do I still need to press "Submit for review" in iTunes Connect in order for the app to actually get to Apple's review?

```
iTMSTransporter -m upload -f [path to App Store Package] -u [iTunes Connect user name] -p [iTunes Connect password]
```

It sounds like the app goes straight to review with the way the transporter user guide words it, but I wanted to confirm with someone that has worked with this before. I don't want to accidentally be submitting for review when I call this method, when I don't mean to.

I'm new to using iTunes Connect and iTMSTransporter. I'm trying to figure out using iTMSTransporter to automate uploading the app metadata to iTunes Connect as part of a continuous deployment script.

Answer (score 0):

Before, it would go straight to review. This is no longer the case, you have to click "Submit For Review". With the new ItunesConnect, you can upload several binaries for one submission. You have to now manually select which binary you want to submit for review.